# Why does my calculator look odd on other computers?

Tags: javascript, css, html, calculator, calc

Why does my calculator look odd on other computers? Is there any JS, HTML5 or CSS code to make it look the same on all computers? Why does this happen? Have been trying to fix this for hours, have not found any tutorials or StackOverFlow posts that were helpful.

My code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Calc</title>
<style>
.calc {border: groove 6px; margin-left: 530px; margin-right: 530px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; height: 255px;}

input {text-align: center;height: 30px;}

.results {padding-bottom: 7px;}

.top {float: left; padding-left: 20px;}

.numbers {float: left; padding-left: 20px; padding-top: 15px;}

.symbols {float: right; margin-top: -40px; padding-right: 15px;}

button {width: 30px; height: 30px;}
</style>
<script>
function myFunction(clickedId) {
    document.calc.result.value+=clickedId;
}
function Clear() {
    document.calc.result.value="";
}
function compute() {
 try{
 var inp=eval(document.calc.result.value);
 document.calc.result.value=inp;
 }
 catch(err){
  document.calc.result.value="error";
 }
}
function doMath() {
 var inputNum1=document.calc.result.value;
 var result = Math.sqrt(inputNum1);
 document.calc.result.value = result;
}
function myMultiply() {
 var x = parseInt (document.calc.result.value, 10);
 var y = x*x;
 alert(x + " times " + x + " equals " + y);
 return false;
}
function compute() {
 try{
    var inp=eval(document.calc.result.value);
    if(document.calc.result.value==inp)
    inp=inp*inp
    document.calc.result.value=inp;
 }
 catch(err){
  document.calc.result.value="error";
 }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="calc">
<center>
<div class="results">
    <form name="calc">
    <input type="text" name="result" readonly>
    </form>
</div>
<table>
<div class="top">
    <button type="button" id="CLEAR" onclick="Clear()"><font color="#CC0000">C</font></button> <!--Izdzēst rakstīto-->
    <button type="button" id="3.141592653589793" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">π</button> <!--Skaitlis 3.14...-->
    <button type="button" id="6.283185307179586" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">τ</button> <!--Skaitlis 6.28...-->
</div>
<br>
<div class="numbers">
    <button type="button" id="1" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">1</button> <!--Skaitlis 1-->
    <button type="button" id="2" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">2</button> <!--Skaitlis 2-->
    <button type="button" id="3" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">3</button> <!--Skaitlis 3-->
<br>
    <button type="button" id="4" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">4</button> <!--Skaitlis 4-->
    <button type="button" id="5" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">5</button> <!--Skaitlis 5-->
    <button type="button" id="6" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">6</button> <!--Skaitlis 6-->
<br>
    <button type="button" id="7" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">7</button> <!--Skaitlis 7-->
    <button type="button" id="8" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">8</button> <!--Skaitlis 8-->
    <button type="button" id="9" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">9</button> <!--Skaitlis 9-->
<br>
    <button type="button" id="0" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">0</button> <!--Skaitlis 0-->
</div>
<br>
<div class="symbols">
    <button type="button" id="ANS" onclick="compute()">=</button> <!--Vienādības zīme-->
 <br>
 <button type="button" id="+" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">+</button> <!--Plusa zīme-->
 <br>
    <button type="button" id="-" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">-</button> <!--Mīnusa zīme-->
 <br>
    <button type="button" id="*" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">x</button> <!--Reizināšanas zīme-->
 <br>
    <button type="button" id="/" onclick="myFunction(this.id)">÷</button> <!--Dalīšanas zīme-->
 <br>
 <button type="button" id="SQRT" onclick="doMath()">√</button> <!--Kvadrātsakne-->
 <br>
 <button type="button" id="imp*inp" onclick="compute()"><sub>2</sub></button> <!--Kvadrāts-->
</div>
<br>
</table>
</center>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "odd"? Probably some reset scripts (or parts thereof) could help. Most of your problems are probably the result of different user agent styles.

Comment: How does it look different? What browsers work, which ones don't? It's not the computer's fault, it's all up to the browser and its implementation of the CSS/JS standards, and your usage of it. Yes, there is probably more you could be doing to shield yourself from cross-browser woes. And yes, it's largely up to you as the developer to resolve the differences.

Comment: What are "other" computers? What does it look like on your computer?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid and not standard. E.g.: [`<center>` tag is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center), and a [`<table>` should not directly contain `<div>` or `<br>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/table.html). Also the ID naming that you follow goes against [HTML principles](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute): "Identifiers are opaque strings. Particular meanings should not be derived from the value of the id attribute.". My recommendation: fix the code and make it valid and standard, then you (normally) won't face any display issues

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but I suggest you make your code clearer and more maintainable, and therefore easier to debug and less prone to bugs like these in the first place. For example, instead of setting the same `onclick` attribute for each of your number buttons, try something like

```
<button class="number">1</button>
<button class="number">2</button>
<button class="number">3</button>
<!-- etc -->
<button class="number">0</button>
```

and in your JS:

```
var numbers = document.getElementsByClassName("number");
for(var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    numbers[i].onclick = function() {
        // put whatever you want to happen when you click it here
        doWhatever();
    }
}
```

A lot of your other HTML could be improved in a similar way.